# Get element type using id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to get the element type using an id or class with JQuery?

With the HTML as `<div id="elementID"></div>`, using JQuery I want to return `div`.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+get+tag+name&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @squint I looked it up on Google, I couldn't find a thing.  I wonder why it didn't show up in my search or in the `Questions that may already have your answer` section when writing my question.

Comment: No problem. I just like to show people the search I used to find answers. Figure it'll help next time. Using the `site:` search feature helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the [`tagName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

With JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').tagName;
// or
document.querySelector('.elementClass').tagName;
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#elementID').prop('tagName');
```

Comment: Note `.tagName` returns "DIV". Either use `.toLowerCase()` or use `.localName` instead.